# RMI ClassNotFound

Tags: spring, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I get `ClassNotFound` exception, here is code:

Server:

```
<bean id="metaFactoryRmiServiceExporter"
  class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="metaFactoryService"/>
    <property name="service" ref="metaFactoryServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="IMetaFactoryService"/>
    <property name="registryPort" value="1098"/>
</bean>
```

Client:

```
if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
   System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
}
try {
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",1098);
    registry.lookup("metaFactoryService");
    for (String s:registry.list()) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can get the `registry.list()` but lookup throws exception. why ?
I've configured security.policy.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` means you are missing a class from the classpath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java RMI and ClassNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273353/java-rmi-and-classnotfoundexception)