# Class.forName("FQN") throws ClassNotFoundException Intermittently

Tags: java, classloader, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I have a Java based RMI Server in which one of the interface method is like this :

```
public Properties process(String operation, Properties params) {
         Class nodecls = Class.forName("com.example.commands." + operation);
   }
```

This method runs fine all the time but sometimes (say once in a million RMI calls) throws `ClassNotFoundException`. What could be the reason for this? I am sure that the name passed is correct.

Comment: Possible related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273353/java-rmi-and-classnotfoundexception

Comment: can you send the **FQN** class code? perhaps the class in not accessible from your scope.. is it mark with public? or some other modifier?

Answer (score 3):

From [XYZWS - What does Class forname method do?](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17):

> A call to `Class.forName("X")` causes the class named *X* to be dynamically loaded (at runtime). A call to forName("X") causes the class named X to be initialized (i.e., JVM executes all its static block after  class loading). `Class.forName("X")` returns the `Class` object  associated with the "X" class. The returned `Class` object is not an instance of the "x" class itself.
>
> **`Class.forName("X")` loads the class if it not already loaded.** The JVM keeps track of all the classes that have been previously loaded. **This method  uses the `classloader` of the class that invokes it.** The "X" is the fully qualified name of the desired class.

[The tag wiki for](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/classnotfoundexception/info) [classnotfoundexception](/questions/tagged/classnotfoundexception) has a simpler description:

> The Java exception thrown when an application tries to load a class by name. Usually raised by one of:
>
> - the forName method in class Class *[...]*
>
> when no definition for the class with the specified name could be found in the classpath.

Therefore, there can only be two causes for this:

1. The class named `"com.example.commands." + operation` is not present on the Class Path.
2. The `ClassLoader` of the `Class` which your method is in cannot find the `"com.example.commands." + operation` class. Maybe some reflection trick broke it.

However, you should never have to bother with this, as your method wouldn't even compile - it's of a non-`void` return type, while you never included a proper `return` statement.